How to remove the buffer popup in SpaceVim
How can I disable this popup:

I don't even have a clue what it is for, but I hate it :D

You probably have an auto complete plugin. Consult your vimrc, and disable it.

I don't even know how the spacevim folder structure is, nor what plugin this window is; that's why I'm asking here
